Retrieve size of all display monitors connected to windows device
Is it possible to retrieve the height and width (in pixels), colour depth, and scaling factor of each individual monitor connected to my windows device, using Command Prompt commands, PowerShell (preferably without the need for admin privileges), or Python?
Using PowerShell commands such as the below appear to provide width, height, and scaling factor, however the use of Add-Type introduces the need to bypass Constrained Language by use of administrator mode:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens


I can confirm I require a multi monitor environment - also apologies for the above, the power shell commands only provide width, height, and colour depth. Thank you.

To retrieve some width and height (both in px and mm) of each active (i.e. turned on and displaying something) monitor you could use screeninfo (not from standard libs though, but doesn't explicitly require any admin rights)
import screeninfo
print(screeninfo.get_monitors())

Example for two active screens:
[
    Monitor(x=753, y=1440, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=344, height_mm=194, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY1', is_primary=False),
    Monitor(x=0, y=0, width=3440, height=1440, width_mm=797, height_mm=334, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY4', is_primary=True)
]

